# Dataframe rows to json

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with many rows and columns of the form (this is an oversimplified dataframe):

```
    id  dur         proto   service     state   attack_cat  label
0   1   0.121478    tcp     dns         FIN     Normal      0
1   2   4.287901    udp     ftp         INT     Exploits    1
```

I would like to write all the rows of this dataframe as json items, like for example, for the first row:

```
{"type": "event",
 "subtype": "",
 "datatype": "Instance",
 "domain": "Cyber",
 "created": str(datetime.datetime.now()),
 "details": {id: 1,
            dur: 0.121478,
            proto: tcp,
            service: dns,
            state: FIN,
            attack_cat: Normal,
            label:0}
            }
```

I tried to do something like:

```
{"type": "event",
     "subtype": "",
     "datatype": "Instance",
     "domain": "Cyber",
     "created": str(datetime.datetime.now()),
     "details": dataframe.loc[i].to_dict()
 }
```

and do a for loop through all the rows, but it gives me the error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: `dict` is mutable so it can't be hash, which means a `dict` cannot be in the values of another dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two problems, as far as I can see.

Generally, a python dictionary *can* be the **value** of a dictionary. For example,

```py
dict = {
    "first_name": "robert",
    "last_name": "ren",
    "hist": {"today": 1, "yesterday": 2}
}
```

The value of `hist` is a dict. This means, that from this perspective your code seems to be ok. However, a dictionary **can not** be the *key*, nor can you nest one `dict` in another one. For example,

```py
{{}}
```

gives you the following error

```py
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

If you want to solve this problem, I recommend that you print out each line as you create the dicts to see where it breaks. That said, I guess that `"details": dataframe.loc[i].to_dict()` causes you the trouble.

Second, your first `dict` is invalid as the keys are **not strings**. This should be

```py
{
 "type": "event",
 "subtype": "",
 "datatype": "Instance",
 "domain": "Cyber",
 "created": str(datetime.datetime.now()),
 "details": {
            "id": 1,
            "dur": 0.121478,
            "proto": tcp,
            "service": dns,
            "state": FIN,
            "attack_cat": Normal,
            "label": 0
  }
}
```

Assuming that the variables are defined variables.

**EDIT**

The following code works on my machine.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [1],
    "dur": [0.12],
    "proto": ["tcp"],
    "service": ["dns"],
    "state": ["FIN"],
    "attack_cat": ["Normal"],
    "label": [0]
})


row_list_as_dict = []

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    row_list_as_dict.append({
        "type": "event",
        "subtype": "",
        "datatype": "Instance",
        "domain": "Cyber",
        "details": {
            'id': row["id"],
            'dur': row["dur"],
            'proto': row["proto"],
            'service': row["service"],
            'state': row["state"],
            'attack_cat': row["attack_cat"],
            'label': row["label"]
        }
    })

row_list_as_dict
```